# HTML5 canvas drawImage incorrect image size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hello i have problem i try to drawing image on the canvas with `drawImage` function 50px x 50px on the 50px x 50px canvas, but i get smaller than i need.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    $("canvas").css("width", 50);
    $("canvas").css("height", 50);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 50); //bad here why not drawing 50x50px image on the canvas?           
}
img.src = 'http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="100" height="100" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px">
<canvas id="canvas" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 120px; border: 1px solid #000"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't set a canvas's width and height through CSS. This will stretch / compress the actual canvas, scaling the contents.

Use those old HTML `width` and `height` attributes instead:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 50);
}
img.src = 'http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif';
```

```html
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="100" height="100" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px">
<canvas
    id="canvas"
    style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 120px; border: 1px solid #000"
    width="50"
    height="50">
</canvas>
```

These attributes actually change the canvas's context's width and height, resulting in a image that's exactly the size you expect it to be.

Comment: Well this would have been good to know three hours ago. But I'm very glad I know it now.